How do I switch to a newly created database in GridDB?
After creating a new database using the command:
CREATE DATABASE iotdb;

I'm unsure how to list all available databases and switch to the one I need. I attempted the following command, but it didn't work:
gs_sh> connect $cluster1 userDB

Upon further research, it appears GridDB doesn't provide a method to list all databases. However, switching to a specific database can be done by using the Connection URL format, which includes the database name but didn't help
